# Reload Jquery .on event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with inputs. The user can start type and a JQuery script (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple) autocompletes users text.

The user can also add new inputs to the table with a simple JavaScript createElement and innerHTML function.

The problem arrives when the user adds the new inputs because JQuery doesn't register the new inputs and therefore it **doesn't attach an event handler to autocomplete users text**.

**One solution** that may work (but I couldn't get it to work) is the JQuery .delegate() function.

**EDIT (Added source code):**

https://jsfiddle.net/j8rz7s1q/7/ 
`Can't get the code to format correctly from jsfiddle`

Comment: Did you try .on ?
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Without your code we can't really help you.

Comment: Yes, I tried the documentation site. Added source code. Now the problem should be much more clearer. I tried delegation again and it didn't work

Comment: You'll want to create a function that applies the `.autocomplete()` functionality to an element, and call it on the original input div and any newly created divs.  Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/j8rz7s1q/16/

Comment: @dossy Thank you! It works! Post it as an answer and I will accept it. Can you also explain in broad terms what the script does differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily, binding an event on elements that do not exist yet is handled through delegation, where you bind on a parent element and rely on the event on any children created after the binding to work by bubbling up to the parent, which then can invoke the callback.

In the case of the jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin, it's implemented by applying the autocomplete to an element through its implemented interface, which does its own binding on the elements it's being used on.

In this case, where new DOM elements are being added, we define a function that handles binding the Autocomplete functionality on whatever elements are passed to it, and update the code that creates the new elements to call that function after creation to apply the Autocomplete bindings.

A working demonstration of this is in https://jsfiddle.net/j8rz7s1q/16 and duplicated here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <button onClick="addInputs();" id="button1">Add input</button>
    <p>
      The first input works. The autocomplete works completely but when you add new inputs the new inputs doesn't register to the event handler.
    </p>
    <div>

      <div class="LightBox-box-content">
        <table>
          <tbody class="addInput">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="text" class="input1">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script>
      $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
          "Yes", "No",
        ];

        function split(val) {
          return val.split(/,\s*/);
        }

        function extractLast(term) {
          return split(term).pop();
        }

        window.setupAutocomplete = function($obj) {
          return $obj
            // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
            .on("keydown", function(event) {
              if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
                event.preventDefault();
              }
            })
            .autocomplete({
              minLength: 0,
              source: function(request, response) {
                // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                  availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
              },
              focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
              },
              select: function(event, ui) {
                var terms = split(this.value);
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push("");
                this.value = terms.join("");


                return false;
              }
            });
        };
        
        setupAutocomplete($(".input1"));
      });

    </script>

    <script>
      function addInputs() {
        var div = document.createElement('tr');
        div.innerHTML = '<tr>\
  <td>\
      <input type="text" class="input1">\
  </td>\
  </tr>';
  
     setupAutocomplete($('input', div));
  
        document.getElementsByClassName('addInput')[0].appendChild(div);
      }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

From http://api.jquery.com/on/

> Delegated event handlers have the advantage that they can process
>   events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a
>   later time.By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Then, you just need to change the following example to match the elements that you have:

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: I have added jsfiddle link. I tried this but still can't get it working. I got the autocomplete script from JQuery https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Comment: As @ry4nolson said, you probably need to instantiate the autocomplete plugin for every new input. For that you can just call something like `$(".input1").last().autocomplete({ .. all code from autocomplete .. })` after the `document.getElementsByClassName('addInput')[0].appendChild(div)`.  Also, you could also bind the onclick in this very same chain

Comment: that jsfiddle seems to work for me: autocomplete on Yes|No values is showing up for all input fields. What is the problem now?

Answer (score 2):

you need to use a delegate event to handle newly added elements

something like:

```
$(document).on("keydown", "tr input", function() {})
```

Comment: I have added jsfiddle link. I tried this but still can't get it working. I got the autocomplete script from JQuery https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Comment: it looks like you're gonna need to instantiate the autocomplete plugin each time you add a new input.

Comment: Ok and how do I do that?

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a matter of event delegation, unfortunately.  See my answer: https://jsfiddle.net/j8rz7s1q/16

Comment: @dossy Thank you! It works! Post it as an answer and I will accept it. Can you also explain in broad terms what the script does differently?

Comment: @SourceFog dossy's script initializes the autocomplete on the newly added input.